# Programmatically edit an email body after it has been sent

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am building an outlook addon, which adds an individual signature with an unique URL for rating in it. So, far so good. I also want that the url should not be saved in the "Sent" email folder. Is there any way to edit the sent email text and remove the url after the email has been sent ?

I am using following event for editing the email before it has been sent.

```
Application.ItemSend += new
                        Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can make Outlook delete the message after sending it - just set the `MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit` property to true.

You can also process the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder to modify the message immediately after it is sent and moved to Sent Items.